# Attempting to pull just filename from backtick

Tags: perl

I have an issue where I am attempting to pull just a filename from the output of running a backtick, my code is as follows:

```
$var = `munpack -f filename`;
```

If anyone is familiar with mpack the output will be something like:

```
tempdesc.txt: File exists
file_20130620.zip (application/octet-stream)
```

I am trying to just get the filename, however, all my attempted regexes have failed. I have even tried to just remove the linebreaks and then attempt to process the information and I cannot. I thought they could just be whitespace and remove the whitespace but those regexes have failed. I could go through and list every regex I have tried to pull this data and I can provide that if necessary, but maybe someone has something that could work. I can't produce any matches that id like nor alter the output in any way. So just to be clear im looking for something that will output me just the filename ex: file_20130620.zip

Some suggestions given with output:

```
$var =~ m{^(.+?)\(}m and print "$1\n";
output:
tempdesc.txt: File exists
file_20130620.zip 

($filename) = $var =~ /(?s:.*\n)?(.*) \([^)]+\)\n/;
output:
tempdesc.txt: File exists
file_20130620.zip 

if($var =~/\S+: [^\n]+\n(\S+) [^\n]+\n/) { printf $1; }
output:
tempdesc.txt: File exists
```

Fix per ysth:

```
$var = `munpack -f filename 2>/dev/null`; #will remove 'tempdesc.txt: File exists'
```

Comment: why not just grep the raw mime text for the filename? it'll be in there somewhere already.

Comment: `foo = (command); $foo =~ s/.*\W(\w+\.zip).*/$1/s; print $foo`

Comment: @Kevin if I use this method only: tempdesc.txt: File exists appears in $foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the filename is before a space before a parenthesized mimetype on the last line of output:

```
($filename) = $var =~ /(?s:.*\n)?(.*) \([^)]+\)\n/;
```

Though I'd rather create a temporary directory (use File::Temp) and unpack in it and just look for what file(s) are there than parse the output.

It is possible that the File Exists warning isn't actually in `$var`, but is appearing in your output because munpack is writing it to stderr (which doesn't get captured by backticks.)
Try doing `munpack -q -f ...` or `munpack -f ... 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: This will remove: (application/octet-stream), however, tempdesc.txt: File exists still appears.

Comment: my regex will skip past that if it is in `$var`; I suspect you did something wrong.  Please show the output from `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; print Dumper $var; print Dumper $filename;` (after the code in my answer)

Comment: tempdesc.txt: File exists
"file_20130620.zip (application/octet-stream)\n"
"file_20130620.zip"

Comment: munpack -f ... 2>/dev/null worked. It does appear its writing it to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the filename is followed by a parenthesized description, something like this works:

```
$var =~ m{^(.+?)\(}m and print "$1\n";
```

The `\m` modifier treats a string as one with multiple lines so that you can match `^` and `$` on any line.  See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: If I run this the output is: tempdesc.txt: File exists
file_20130620.zip . It will remove (application/octet-stream) from the last line only.

Comment: Can you run the output through `od` as: `munpack -f filename|od -xa` and post that?

Comment: tempdesc.txt: File exists
          0   .   z   i   p  sp

Answer (score 0):

I put your sample output to file1.txt as I dont have mpack utility installed.
And this regexp works

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $var = `more file1.txt`;

if($var =~/\S+: [^\n]+\n(\S+) [^\n]+\n/)
{
    printf $1;
}
```

Comment: If I run this code the output I receive is: tempdesc.txt: File exists

Comment: you probably wanted cat, not more.